# How do I test these hypotheses? which regression?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I'm currently busy writing an essay, but struggling with some things in the data analysis. This is my my conceptual model (simplified):

$A$---\
.......\
........$C$
......../
$B$---/

where $A$ is a nominal variable, so it needs to bee dummified, $B$ is a scale variable, and $C$ is a scale variable.

My hypotheses:

- $H_1$: $A$ has a positive relationship to $C$
- $H_2$: $B$ has a positive relationship to $C$
- $H_3$: $A$ has a more positive relationship to $C$ than $B$ to $C$.

How do I test this? I thought of testing $H_1$ and $H_2$ with a linear regression, but how do I test $H_3$?
And how do I control for variables?

Comment: I feel you need to work a bit more on the question. It is unclear what you are trying to show with your diagram above and it is also unclear for what variables you wish to control. It is also not clear what you mean by a positive relationship between a nominal variable and an interval variable.

Comment: If's not confidential the context would also be of helpful. Beginner often translate their research question incorrectly into a statistical hypothesis. For example, when looking at 3 are you really interesting in the effect sizes or which one is better for the purpose of prediction?

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with $H_1$:

If $A$ is nominal how would you define "positive". A positive relationship means more of $A$ leads to more of $C$. A classic example of a nominal variable would be a respondent's religion. How would you define more in that case; are muslims more than catholics, and catholics more than ...? In other words, if $A$ is nominal than $H_1$ does not make sense.

There is also  a problem with $H_3$:

If you turn $A$ into a set of indicator variables (some prefer the word dummies, I don't), then you have multiple effects for $A$. How do you want to compare them with the single effect of $B$? One possible way to think about this is sheaf coefficients (Heise 1972)), but whether or not that is the right solution for your problem depends on your problem.

Another thing you will want to think about when considering $H_3$: Do you want to adjust the effect of $A$ on $C$ for $B$ and the effect of $B$ on $C$ for $A$?

Heise, David R. (1972). Employing nominal variables, induced variables, and block variables in path analysis. *Sociological Methods & Research*, 1(2): 147--173.

Comment: Typically that variable already exists and there is no need to create anything new.

Comment: That question is too open ended for us to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: I suggest you find someone localy who can help you face to face.